# How to center GWT html page?

Tags: html, css, gwt

I tried to center my GWT html page with the following css

```
body {
   color:#000000;
   font:1px Impact;
   text-align:center;
   width:1000px;
   margin:auto;
}
```

I also tried several different kinds for margin like

```
margin: 1px auto;
```

or

```
margin: 1% auto;
```

The page shows up in the middle for a short time, then switches to the left side.
I got the code working outside GWT.

What is the problem?

Comment: Please post the GWT code also.

Comment: some other css loading late causing an override? Use your browser's DOM inspector to view the css rules applied to your element. any decent inspection will tell you which rules are currently in force and where they came from.

Comment: Don't use absolute width because it will not work on different resolution or on different system.

Answer (score 0):

> Add a new `div` in your HTML/JSP file that is `center` algined and now add your root component in that `div`.

Entry Point class:

```
public class GWTProject implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {    
        RootPanel.get("container").add(initComponent);    
    }
}
```

HTML/JSP:

```
...
<body>
    <div id="container" align="center"></div>
</body>
...
```

Its as simple as it is.